# Local storage is undefined jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Getting undefined error while click on button.
Here you can see my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        if(!localStorage.utm){
            localStorage.utm = window.location.search;

        } else if (window.location.search == ""){

        } else if(window.location.search != localStorage.utm){
            localStorage.utm = window.location.search;

        }
    });

$('#signup, #login').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    storedUrl = localStorage.utm;
    if(this.href.includes("?")){
        storedUrl = storedUrl.replace("?", "&");
    }

    var finalURL = this.href + storedUrl;
    var linkURL = this.getAttribute("href");

    if(linkURL.includes("app.hirefirst")){
        localStorage.utm = '';
        window.location.href = finalURL;
    } else {

        window.location.href = linkURL;
    }

});
```

Can anyone told me what I'm doing mistake here?

Thanks

Comment: I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Comment: That shouldn't happen if you really have that `ready` handler and the click is after the `ready` handler runs, but you can easily handle it by changing `storedUrl = localStorage.utm;` to `storedUrl = localStorage.utm || "";`. BTW, you need to declare that variable (as far as we can see from the question, anyway, it's undeclared).

Comment: (Please use the "edit" link to improve the question, rather than just posting a comment.)

Comment: you can always check the properties existence first...```console.log(localStorage)```